# Make DTMF Dectator For My Mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator

When a third party calls a phone I'd like to be able to detect what buttons they press. I figure I could record the voice downstream and then after the call run some algorithm to figure out what keys where pressed during the call. so how can i do this...which functions and methods should i used......?